# UITableView Swipe to delete not working properly on iOS8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8, swipe

I have a view controller, having a uitableview inside a uiview. The delegate and datasource embeded properly and everything is working fine.

I am using commitEditingStyle and canEditRowAtIndexPathMethods delegate methods for swipe to delete functionality.

The usage of methods are as follows.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSDictionary *dataElement = [cartArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *productId = [dataElement objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *productSizeId = [dataElement objectForKey:@"beden_id"];

    [self deleteTableRowWithId:productId sizeId:productSizeId];

  }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}
```

The swipe gesture and delegate methods are working very fine without any problem on iOS7 tested both on emulator and device, however on iOS8 the swipe gesture doesn't work properly.

I tested this on iOS8 using iPhone 6 and to activate swipe I need to swipe like 20 times or more and from the edge table cell, sometimes cant even manage to get the swipe delete button at all.

I checked and tried most of the solutions on stack-overflow. Any help or suggestion will be deeply appreciated.

Hierarchy in the storyboard is like in the picture below.

[image: Storyboard Table Cell]

Comment: The swipe gesture is implemented using a scrollview. Is there anything in your cell that could collide with your swipe gesture? E.g. another scrollview?

Comment: No scroll view or gesture recognizer and weird thing swiping works perfect on ios7.

Comment: The same is my situation.Can you please help?What was the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue, swipes would only work about 20% of the time on both simulator and device. In my case it was caused by ECSlidingViewController (a popular sliding menu implementation), which sets up a horizontal pan gesture to open the menu. This gesture needs to be disabled in the `viewDidAppear:` of the controller where you want swipe-to-delete to work properly:

```
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];

     // Disable sliding menu pan gesture so it doesn't conflict with table view swipe-to-delete
     self.slidingViewController.panGesture.enabled = NO;
}
```

Make sure to re-enable the pan gesture if you want other controllers to be able to use it:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Re-enable sliding menu pan gesture so other controllers can use it
    self.slidingViewController.panGesture.enabled = YES;
}
```

See this pull request for more info on the issue: https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/pull/70

Long story short, whether you're using ECSlidingViewController or not, make sure there are no other pan gestures set up that collide with the swipe-to-delete pan gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there are other gesture recognizers than just the panGesture. If you want to retain the pan gesture or other recognizers, and still allow swipe to delete, I have accomplished such with the following category in the visible view controller:

```
@interface UIView (CellSwipeAdditions)
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
@end

@implementation UIView (CellSwipeAdditions)
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
        return YES;
    }
@end
```